# A word for playing roles with hand puppets

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

When kids play with hand puppets and they act different roles, is it correct to call such games "role playing games," or is there any other, better word for it.

Thanks,
Tommy.

Comment: *(Hand-)puppeteering*?

Comment: not sure if puppeteering can fit hand puppets and acting roles.

Answer (score 3):

The word is **puppetry** or **puppet-play**

> [**puppet-playing**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/puppet-playing) - The action of staging a puppet play; puppetry.
>
> - Puppetry is a form of theatre or performance that involves the manipulation of puppets – inanimate objects, often resembling some type of human or animal figure, that are animated or manipulated by a human called a puppeteer. Such a performance is also known as a puppet play.  (from [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppetry))
>   [image]

Comment: So the kids "played" puppetry. Or the kids "did puppet playing?" What will be the verb that will go along with puppet playing games?

Comment: @Tommy  The kids were puppet playing when I arrived.

Comment: @Tommy  ... or "they were playing with puppets".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a generic term, I have usually heard these types of games (children acting out different roles, with or without props like dolls or puppets) called "playing pretend". "Role-playing game" is almost exclusively used for structured games typically played by adults.

Comment: Thanks Alan, 
They were playing pretend games with puppets -or- they were playing make believe game with puppets. What sounds better?

Comment: @Tommy Either one works, but my instinct is to omit "games" - just "they were playing pretend/make believe with puppets". Having a hard time finding documentation of this usage, though, I'm just going off what I've experienced.